# Node js working single thread but how fast?

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, multithreading

General web platforms like PHP, Java, .Net is using a thread for one request.

```
    CLIENT-------------------------------SERVER

    Request1 --------------------------> Thread1 ------> 
    Request2 --------------------------> Thread2 ------> GO database, file, etc.
    Request3 --------------------------> Thread3 ------>
```

I am reading node js processing model. It is a bit different. But I confused a bit. Request is binding async process by a single thread.

```
    CLIENT-------------------------------SERVER

    Request1 -------------------------->            Worker1 ----> 
    Request2 --------------------------> Thread-->  Worker2 ----> GO database, file, etc.
    Request3 -------------------------->            Worker3 ---->
```

Multiple request should be slower then PHP or Java process. Because multiple request is binding single thread. Is this true?

And second question, is the same thread givind response that coming from worker thread?

Comment: By being single threaded, node.js can only receive or respond to 1 request at a time. That doesn't necessarily make it slower or faster than the other languages, it just makes it different. The relative speed will of course depend on how each server is coded. It is also possible (and common) to run multiple instances of the same nodejs app in a cluster, resulting in the use of multiple threads, allowing an additional concurrent request to be received or responded to at a time.

Comment: single thread means it can only do one thing at once, but well-written nodejs code spends >99% of it's time waiting for hardware, like a DB over a intranet connection. Single thread is actually better at such waiting because each waiting connection uses a lot less resources than systems that use a whole thread per connection. you can also easily cluster node processes so that you have many threads doing the same thing, to take advantage of multi-core CPUs, provisioning, and load-balancing.